# Não consegui entender bem como esse código funciona

Tags: python

Vi esse código para fazer a transposição da matriz mas não consegui entender bem como ele funciona.

Pra mim esse `row[i]` parece mais como um "marcador" de um índice, por exemplo, linha 1, linha 2, linha 3 e linha 4. Não entendi bem como ele funciona.

Além disso o `range(2)` também me confunde porque pra mim range era usado para um intervalo de números.

Alguém consegue me explicar?

```
matrix = [[1, 2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
transpose = [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(2)]
print(transpose)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se for assim, fica mais fácil de entender?

```
matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
transpose = []
for i in range(2):
    linha = []
    for row in matrix:
        linha.append(row[i])

    transpose.append(linha)
```

Isso é equivalente ao que a [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) está fazendo.

---

> *Além disso o `range(2)` também me confunde porque pra mim range era usado para um intervalo de números.*

Sim, `range` serve para isso mesmo, o que muda é o que você faz com esses números.

De forma geral, `range(n)` representa o intervalo entre zero e `n - 1` (o `n` não é incluso no `range`). Então `range(2)` representa o intervalo entre zero e 1 (ou seja, apenas os números 0 e 1).

Então o `for i in range(2)` está servindo para percorrer os números 0 e 1, e depois, para cada "linha" da matriz, pega-se o elemento que está na posição `i`. Em outras palavras:

- na primeira iteração, `i` vale zero.
- cada elemento de `matrix` é uma lista (o primeiro elemento é a lista `[1, 2]`, o segundo é a lista `[3, 4]`, etc). O `for row in matrix` percorre essas listas

  - dentro do `for row in matrix`, pega-se o primeiro elemento de cada lista (`row[i]`, e como `i` vale zero, pega-se o `row[0]`, que é o primeiro elemento da lista)
  - ou seja, este `for` vai adicionando o `1`, depois o `3`, depois o `5` e por fim o `7`, todos em uma mesma lista
  - depois, esta lista `[1, 3, 5, 7]` é adicionada em `transpose`
- na segunda iteração, `i` vale 1, e agora `linha` será uma lista com o segundo elemento de cada sub-lista de `matrix`

---

Neste caso, achei "errado" o uso de `range(2)`, pois o código só funciona se todas as sublistas de `matrix` têm exatamente dois elementos (se tiver mais, eles seriam ignorados). Uma forma um pouco mais [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052), sem depender de um valor fixo, seria:

```
matrix = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
transpose = []
for row in zip(*matrix):
    transpose.append(list(row))

print(transpose) # [[1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 4, 6, 8]]
```

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) serve para percorrer várias listas de uma vez, retornando tuplas contendo os elementos de cada uma delas. Ao passar `*matrix`, com o asterisco, estou fazendo o [*unpacking*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), ou seja, é como se eu passasse cada uma das sub-listas como argumento para `zip`.

Com isso, na primeira iteração do `for`, a variável `row` será uma tupla contendo o primeiro elemento de cada uma das sub-listas. Na segunda iteração, será uma tupla contendo o segundo elemento de cada uma e assim por diante.

Depois, dentro do *loop*, eu transformo esta tupla em uma lista e adiciono em `transpose`.

Se quiser, também pode usar uma *list comprehension*:

```
transpose = [ list(row) for row in zip(*matrix) ]
```

Claro que dá para melhorar mais, pois o código não verifica se todas as sub-listas possuem o mesmo tamanho, etc (ou seja, ele assume que a matriz está corretamente preenchida). Mas a ideia básica é essa.

Comment: muito obrigada, ajudou bastante!!